# Dynamic Validation of a HTML Forms using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, validation

I have designed a customer form using HTML and PHP. But now the problem is, to validate the form. I want validation like an asp.net page does it: as soon as the textbox control loses its focus, the validator show the status.

Is that possible in php?

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible without Javascript support, even ASP.NET uses Javascript to assist in validation of input fields in a form.

You are looking at either an AJAX solution, or JS validation client side + PHP server side validation (always need to do client + server validation).

But no, there is not pure PHP for client side validation, PHP is server side.

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you want the validation to occur "when the textbox loses focus" that implies that your intention is to do client-side validation. I HIGHLY discourage you from doing this as client side "anything" shouldn't be trusted. All validation should be done server side.

Now, you may want to use some jquery to enhance the "user experience" of your form by doing the validation in the browser but make no mistake, this is for show only.

The following code should lead you in the right direction

```
// $clean_post: Assumes you already sanitized for SQL injection attack vectors and
// that you have already ensured proper character encoding.

// Example is for a hypothetical first name
if( empty( $clean_post[ 'first_name' ] ) )
{
    // Do something to let the user know that first name is required
}
else
{
    // They entered a first name, this is good. Now check for
    // invalid characters. We will allow A-Z , backtick, apostrophe, space and dash
    if( preg_match( "/[^a-zA-Z `'\-]/" , $clean_post[ 'first_name' ] ) )
    {
        // Do something because they have illegal characters.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use Javascript/JQuery to validate in real time. If you must use PHP to validate the input, you can use an AJAX call to a PHP script that validates the input and returns. Below is something like what the AJAX call would look like that takes the value from your input box and passes it to a PHP script. If the PHP script prints "passed" then all is good, but if it doesn't then it removes the value and alerts the user.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    data:'value='+$('#inputFieldID').val();
    url:'path-to-validate-script.php',
    success:function(msg){
        if (msg != "passed") {
            $('#inputFieldID').val('');
            alert("Invalid Input!");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer completely ignores the fact that you can't rely on front-end validation alone.  Turn off javascript and your solution just became a block of useless code.  Yes, Javascript for the front end validation, but you're only giving half of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing about validation:  Client side validation looks good and can be very quick to setup.  It's better for the user because it can "do more" to indicate problems (vs just php without javascript)

But, and this is a BIG but, it's not foolproof.  You turn off Javascript and your validation is dead in the water.  Relying on anything javascript or jQuery is being irresponsible with your data input....So, you'll have to rely on a hybrid solution--front end and back end.  And don't forget data sanitizing, either....or you'll end up with [little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) as one of your site users.

My company does forms as a core part of its business.  If I was to do custom validation I'd go crazy and throw myself off the roof.  I [use this script](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) to save time....it's quick, effective, and foolproof, just a line or two of code to include and a couple of words in the class to make it work.  Again, this is just the front-end portion of the two-pronged hybrid approach.

On the back end, when you submit you just have to have your function return the problem inputs if it fails validations and indicate back to the UI so that it can throw warnings.  On my apps, I have a centralized "problem" alert area on top of the form that's initially hidden that catches all back-end validation issues from PHP and displays them in one spot.  If they take the time to override my front-end validation, they deserve to have to wade through a huge error message, I figure.